# Replicating models in Keras and Tensorflow for a multi-threaded setting

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement the asynchronous version of actor-critic in Keras and TensorFlow. I am using Keras just as a front-end for building my network layers (I am updating the parameters directly with tensorflow). I have a `global_model` and one main tensorflow session. But inside each thread I am creating a `local_model` which copies parameters from the `global_model`. My code looks something like this

```
def main(args):
    config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False,allow_soft_placement=True)
    sess = tf.Session(config=config)
    K.set_session(sess) # K is keras backend
    global_model = ConvNetA3C(84,84,4,num_actions=3)

    threads = [threading.Thread(target=a3c_thread, args=(i, sess, global_model)) for i in range(NUM_THREADS)]

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

def a3c_thread(i, sess, global_model):
    K.set_session(sess) # registering a session for each thread (don't know if it matters)
    local_model = ConvNetA3C(84,84,4,num_actions=3)
    sync = local_model.get_from(global_model) # I get the error here

    #in the get_from function I do tf.assign(dest.params[i], src.params[i])
```

I get a user warning from Keras

> UserWarning: The default TensorFlow graph is not the graph associated
>   with the TensorFlow session currently registered with Keras, and as
>   such Keras was not able to automatically initialize a variable. You
>   should consider registering the proper session with Keras via
>   `K.set_session(sess)`

followed by a tensorflow error on the `tf.assign` operation saying operations must be on the same graph.

> ValueError: Tensor("conv1_W:0", shape=(8, 8, 4, 16),
>   dtype=float32_ref, device=/device:CPU:0) must be from the same graph
>   as Tensor("conv1_W:0", shape=(8, 8, 4, 16), dtype=float32_ref)

I am not exactly sure what is going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The error comes from Keras because `tf.get_default_graph() is sess.graph` is returning `False`. From the TF docs, I see that `tf.get_default_graph()` is returning the default graph for the current thread. The moment I start a new thread and create a graph, it is built as a separate graph specific to that thread. I can solve this issue by doing the following,

```
with sess.graph.as_default():
   local_model = ConvNetA3C(84,84,4,3)
```